# Vectors vs Dynamic arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

I find it possible to initialise arrays dynamically in C++.
 By this i mean :

```
int n;
int ar[n];
```

works fine.

So what is the difference between this and **vectors** ?

Comment: Try to compile with `-Wall -pedantic` and the difference should be clear :)

Comment: Variable Length Arrays are not standard C++ but appear to be supported as an extension by your compiler.

Comment: Variable length arrays are not part of standard C++. Some compilers support them as an extension to the language, but don't rely on that.

Comment: Variable Length Arrays, even when supported, have a good chance to be allocated on the stack, which has limited size; try `int n=100000; int arr[n]; arr[100]=0` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The one thing is that VLA (and `int arr[n]` with `n` being something else than a `constexpr` is a variable length array) are not supported by C++ standard. So even if some compilers accept it, it is at least not portable.

The other thing is that a `vector` can adapt it's size dynamically, i.e. it "increases" on demand, and you can let it shrink. This is not possible with a VLA, since - once defined for a particular `n`, allocates memory according to `n` elements, and it cannot grow or shrink any more afterwards.

Further, VLA's in their typical use have a good chance to be allocated on the stack, which has a rather limited size compared to the heap. Vectors allocate memory on the heap, so they usually can get much bigger. So with VLAs you might run into memory problems for `n`s where you would have clearly no problem with vectors. Try, for example, `int n=100000; int arr[n]; arr[100]=0` and see what happens.

Comment: I don't think most modern desktops are going to have a problem allocating 100000 ints on the stack. Some could even handle a million, though most would choke on 10 million.